# Setting Firebase Functions Gen 2 (Firestore Triggers) Region at Function Level - Without Using setGlobalOptions

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

How do we set `region` at the functions level for Firebase Functions Gen 2 [Cloud Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events?gen=2nd)?

I do not want to set using `setGlobalOptions`. I want to set it at the function level instead.

If I was setting it at the function level for the `onCall` function I would do this:

```TypeScript
export const helloworld = onCall(
  { region: "australia-southeast1" }, // Region is set here
  () => {
    logger.info("Hello World!");
  },
);
```

But how can it be done for Firestore triggers such as `onDocumentUpdated`?

```TypeScript
export const userupdated = onDocumentUpdated(
  "users/{userId}",
  () => {
    logger.info("IT WORKS!");
  },
);
```

Comment: See the duplicate, you need to pass an object as follows: `{ region: "australia-southeast1", document: "users/{userId}" }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Firebase Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md#firestoreondocumentcreated_2), there is a second signature for onDocumentUpdated method that receives an opts parameter, that´s where you can set the Document, Region, Memory and Timeout.